# Isolating 'low spots' in a DEM

Tags: qgis

I am looking to isolate 'low spots' i.e. flat areas in the landscape that will likely accumulate water. I have found one way to do this but I am looking for other methods of extracting these areas from a DEM. This is what I have done so far:

1. Converted DEM to slope
2. Used the Focal Statistic tool on SAGA to get the mean slope for a radius of 10 m (I also experimented with 5 m).
3. Created a boolian raster for slope values <= than a certain value. I experimented with 1 degree and 2 degree slope. Two degree seems to work alright.

So far, this method works much better than just creating a boolian raster of <= the slope threshold without using focal statistics. I am looking for smooth polygons on where the flat areas may be and where they may accumulate water. The goal is to make polygons of these areas so industry can avoid these areas. Are there other tools that can be used to extract low spots of a certain size?

Comment: If you're willing to try a `GRASS-GIS` solution, the module `r.fill.dir` has a flag `-f` to find and create a raster of undrained areas.